# Desde Flutter escuchar un cambio de un campo determinado en Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hola chicos necesito conocer cuando se modifica el valor de un campo que esta dentro de una Documento y a la vez dentro de una Colección en Firebase.
Yo lo tengo hecho como muestra la imagen pero a pesar que no obtengo error no parece funcionar por que el código nunca llega a los print colocados allí.
Que me está faltando?

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entra para nada? ni muestra los datos que trae esa colección? , estás seguro qeu es la colección correcta con el document id correcto? puedes poner un pantallazo de tu collection

Comment: No entra para nada. No se si porque mas adelante se consultan los datos en otros StreamBuilder pero no logro capturar nada. Ahi te paso la captura que pides

Comment: que cambios haces en tu bd para que esperes cambios en el listening? que editas?

Comment: Lo que dese es chequear donde dice estado  = abierto  cambie a ''cerrado''

Comment: Entonces debes de escuchar al Documento Urk...  no a la sub colección tablero

Comment: eso pense pero me da error sino escucho una coleccion.  Firestore.instance.collection('TVBingoEventos')
    .document('UrKkYV6xz3Eln5TsMCtu');

Comment: eso me acabo de dar cuenta con tu comentario ultimo. PEro jamas use esto y estoy aprendiendo asi que te pido disculpas por mis brutez. Cambia a DocumentPref.. pero algo falla mira mi ultima captura

Comment: Prueba est cambio, así como estaba inicialmente, pero solo escucha a esto : Firestore.instance.collection('TVBingoEventos')  <-- nada más, me dices como va, ya que ahí estás escuchando add/edit/delete de los documentos de esa colección

Comment: No hay caso prove como me dices y nada! cambie 
 DocumentReference eventsReference  de CollectionReference eventsReference pero naranja. ME rindo con esto por hoy. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ok, te dejo este link por si quieres escuchar solo a un documento: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498200/666221

Comment: El código se comparte como texto. Sólo se usan imágenes en las preguntas si es absolutamente necesario.

Comment: fue necesario!! gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que sea un problema en
`eventReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot)=> _onEventsSnapshot);`

esa función recibe un valor del tipo QuerySnapshot pero no se lo estas pasando.

```
eventReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot)=> _onEventsSnapshot(snapshot));
```